# TypeError when using string.join() in Python

Tags: python, string

I am writing a very simple function that, given a string as input, parses the string into sentences, reverses the words of each sentence, and returns the reversed sentences but in the given sentence order. I am struggling with the `string.split()` and `string.join()` built-in methods and am getting a TypeError when I run the following python program.

```
import string

def reverseSentences(str):
    senList = str.split('.')
    for i, item in enumerate(senList[:]):
        senList[i] = string.join(item.split(' ').reverse(), ' ')
    return string.join(senList, '.') + '.'
```

When I try to print a call to this function it gives me a generic TypeError. Thanks for enduring my n00bishness.

Comment: `string.join` is old cruft (and removed in newer Python versions) - use `' '.join(reversed(...))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
>> str = 'a1 b2'
>> ' '.join(x[::-1] for x in str.split())
'1a 2b'
```

In function form:

```
def reverseSentences(str):
  return ' '.join(x[::-1] for x in str.split())
```

Notice that `x[::-1]` is way faster than `reversed()` ([Reverse a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python)).

Comment: I think, OP just needs - `' '.join(str.split()[::-1])`. You are reversing each word.

Comment: You are right! This description confused me "reverses the words of each sentence". And OP didn't give a example input/output. It was fun to quick code anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

`item.split(' ').reverse()` does not return the list, rather it does the reverse in place. So, your join is same as:

```
string.join(None, ' ')
```

Clearly a problem. You should rather use `reversed()` function:

```
string.join(reversed(item.split(' ')), ' ')
```

And rather than `string.join` function, use the method defined in `string` class in newer Python version.

```
' '.join(reversed(item.split(' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

In line:

```
senList[i] = string.join(item.split(' ').reverse(), ' ')
```

.reverse() reverse items in list object itself but returns nothing, so you can't use join in this way.

divide this line in two:

```
import string

def reverseSentences(text):
    senList = text.split('.')
    for i, item in enumerate(senList[:]):
        splited = item.split(' ')
        splited.reverse()
        senList[i] = string.join(splited, ' ')
    return string.join(senList, '.') + '.'
```